# What is the expect library for?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I came across the NPM package called [expect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expect?activeTab=readme) being used alongside the `jest` package in a `package.json` file.

It is also from the Jest team, but it is hard to find in the docs why you would want to use it on its own. Is it necessary to run Jest tests? Is it for TypeScript users?

Can anybody provide context why you would want to use it in addition to the `jest` package?

Comment: Did you click through to https://jestjs.io/docs/expect?

Comment: It's simply one of the [Jest packages](https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/main/packages/expect) used by [other Jest packages](https://github.com/facebook/jest/search?l=JSON&q=%22expect%22). Typically you wouldn't need to include it directly

Comment: Some other packages may use it, like Playwright, but normally a standard user wouldn’t need it by itself. Certainly you don’t need the separate standalone library in order to use any packages who already depend on it.

Comment: @Spectric he may have meant, when would you use it by itself as its own package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t know their reason for separating out the package by itself. Perhaps to break up their own repo. Maybe to make it usable by other frameworks. I know [Playwright uses it](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions) to basically extend or build their assertions on top of it.

That being said, unless you plan on building a new test runner/framework or somehow extending it, then you probably don’t need it yourself. It’s already built in/depended on and provided by those frameworks, so you wouldn’t need it in addition.

I’m not sure why it was in your project, but I’d say it’ll likely be pretty obvious if it was needed if you remove it and tests start breaking. Theoretically if it is somehow used (which again seems unlikely since jest already includes it), it should only be for testing, so there really should be no risk in just removing it and seeing if they still work.

Hope that helps!